# most simple SQL implementation in standard C to be used in linux-based ARM terminals

Tags: sql, c, embedded-database

Do you know some open-source very tiny SQL server implementation possibly in 1 *.c (or several) file without external dependencies ? Implementation should be very basic - support of most simple forms of select/insert/delete/update... No DDL is needed (albeit it would be good to have). Only basic 1 user at-a-timer operations - (no multi-user mode or resolving db locks is needed). Simply operates on some 1 db file (possibly in text mode). ??
Sources must be in standard portable C.

Very thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious choice is [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

You can add "-DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION" to avoid external dependencies.

Comment: hm, thanks but I've tried sqlite-amalgamation version, but it is too much bloated for my simple needs. Most importantly i can't compile it on my system - I can't use posix threads for example nor I want multi-threading in SQL implemenation (1 user at-a-time is just enough for me). And also I get some other compile errors - for example missing declarations:
ftruncate, MAP_FAILED, PROT_READ, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER', ... 
Also missing external includes:
<dlfcn.h>, <sys/mman.h>, etc.. and bunch of warnings. So - no this is too bloated and too dependable on external stuff.

Comment: Most bloat comes from dealing with multi-user operations. But i said that i don't want multi-user scalability- 1 user-at-a-time is OK for me :-) I just need some abstraction of `select update insert delete` from file ...

Comment: Have you tried compiling with -DSQLITE_CONFIG_SINGLETHREAD ? There's other configuration options to slim it further.

Comment: Ah, you should use -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=0 . It still complains about undefined references to the dynamic linker though.

Comment: If you add -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION you will avoid the undefined references to the dynamic linker.